# Why are column names case Insensitive on SQL Server when accessing through ASP pages but case-SENSITIVE when accessing through PHP mssql module?

Tags: php, sql-server

Why are column names case Insensitive on SQL Server when accessing through ASP pages but case-SENSITIVE when accessing through PHP mssql module?

For example, we have an IIS server with a lot of ASP pages that access our SQL Server.  The column names from tables retrieved from the database are all case insensitive.  You can type them all uppercase or lower or mixed whatever you want and they come back.

However, we have a Linux server running Ubuntu (latest versions) with a fully updated Apache2 and PHP5 fully patched and updated using the mssql module to conect to the sql server, BUT .. all column names are case sensitive.

This poses a problem when a DB admin changes a VIEW and the stored procedure now returns column names all in UPPERCASE instead of lowercase like they were yesterday.

Is there any way to adjust the mssql module?

Here are my settings:

```
MSSQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    1
Library version FreeTDS

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mssql.allow_persistent  On  On
mssql.batchsize 0   0
mssql.charset   no value    no value
mssql.compatability_mode    Off Off
mssql.connect_timeout   5   5
mssql.datetimeconvert   On  On
mssql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.max_procs Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.min_error_severity    10  10
mssql.min_message_severity  10  10
mssql.secure_connection Off Off
mssql.textlimit Server default  Server default
mssql.textsize  Server default  Server default
mssql.timeout   60  60
```

Comment: Why not just always treat column names as case sensitive? If you called a column `FloobSize` then what do you gain by referencing it as `FLOOBSIZE` or `floobsize`? Also, can you explain what you mean by "all column names are case sensitive" - does PHP throw an error if you call `FloobSize` `FLOOBSIZE` instead? What error?

Comment: This is one of those "tabs vs. spaces", "vi vs. emacs", "brace goes at the end of the line vs. next line" arguments... but since I've **always** gone under the presumption that case **always** matters I **never** encounter any issues :-)

Comment: @scunliffe that may be true for keywords etc. (`SELECT` vs. `select`) but I don't think it's quite the exact same argument for user-defined entities. If you named something `splunge_mort` why would you ever reference it in any other way except `splunge_mort`?

Comment: Most likely you're connecting to a case sensitive collation database with one app vs. a case insensitive collation database with the other app. The client stack has no say in the matter.

Comment: @Remus nice catch, from the narrative I assumed both apps were connecting to the same database and talking to the same tables.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's not that simple.  In a perfect world we would just do this of course.  PHP doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't return a value if the case is incorrect.

Comment: I think people are getting confused. The collation refers to the using LIKE statements to do matching of the data within the columns.  I am referring to the actual COLUMN name being referenced in PHP such as $row['product_id']  vs $row['PRODUCT_ID'] ...

Comment: Michael, create a database with a case sensitive collation, create a table with a column called `product_id`, then do `SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM dbo.table` and let us know what happens. I get `Msg 207 Invalid column name`. I think it's PHP or you that is getting confused, not the people trying to help you. Can you clarify, if for nothing else than just to humor us, if ASP and PHP are accessing the same databases or different databases, and whether you have checked if their collation is case-sensitive or case-insensitive? If you can't do that much, I give up.

Comment: No, we dont do select statements directly to the database.  Everything is done through stored procedures. I execute the stored proc and the column names are returned.  In ASP using IIS server I can reference them case insensitive, on PHP using Ubuntu/Apache2 and mssql library I can only reference the column names in the proper case that they were set to.  I'm starting to think there is no solution to this problem ...

Comment: Just to test, I did that, and nothing was returned to the screen and no error appeared in the log.  It just ignores them and continues.  Very strange.